# All Strings to resource

Tags: .net, string, refactoring, resources

Hi I'm Looking For a tool that help me to extract all strings of my code files to Resource File. I Used Coderush and Microsoft add on(resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com) for working with Resource files. but i had to extract strings to resources one by one.
Is there any better option?

Comment: a tool or app for extract all strings to resource not one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from [MSDN Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx).

This is what it says:

To generate a local resource file from an ASP.NET Web page:

1. Open the page for which you want to create a resource file.
2. Switch to Design View.
3. In the Tools menu, click Generate Local Resource.
4. Type values for each resource that you need in your application, and then save the file.
5. If the latest resource changes are not displayed, refresh Design view by switching to Source view and then switching back to Design view.
6. Create resource files for additional languages by following steps 6 and 7 in the preceding procedure.